# React global state update local state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I need to update the local state after a global state is updated.

I tried mapStateToProps but this only maps the global state into the component, it does not update the local state.

Please refer to image to see the code.

after mapStateToProps is updated, the values on the selected_smsf_member should be parsed into the local state which is used to create the form.

I am also open to suggestions of a better approach. Basically what I am trying to do is to show the details of a selected member on a previous component.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could utilize [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops). You can check your props and derive state from it when they change. A few notes though:

- You should initialize your `state.memberDetailsForm` as a falsey value and check that in your `getDerivedState` function otherwise it'll derive your state EVERY TIME the props change which would lead to unexpected consequences.
- I don't know the exact mappings to your code so don't just copy the
  example below and expect it to work.

Implementing this method should get you the output that you want.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  if (!state.memberDetailsForm) {
    return { memberDetailsForm: props.selected_smsf_member }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see `mapStateToProps`, its name says everything, It will map state to props, you can access its variable in your props, like `this.props.selected_smsf_member` in your `component`. If you still want to update your local state, using `getDerivedStateFromProps()`, but read this blog first: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html